# The URL provided is not whitelisted for messenger extensions

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger

I'm getting this issue in botframework dashboard.

I have added google maps as white listed domain.

```
{
  "setting_type" : "domain_whitelisting",
  "domain_action_type": "add",
  "whitelisted_domains":[
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/"
  ]
}
```

Full link :

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B030'40.1%22N+0%C2%B005'02.0%22W/@51.5111351,-0.0860752,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.5111351!4d-0.0838865

Why it does not render as a white-listed domain ?

Edit : I solved this issue.

> https://maps.google.com/maps

I added that link.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, please add your answer, and mark it as the accepted answer.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 9):

Just want to give a more clear answer since I had this issue as well..

The first few pages of the docs on the Messenger API are not too clear.

Use this call to whitelist your domain.
Remember it must be HTTPS.

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "domain_whitelisting",
  "whitelisted_domains" : ["https://petersfancyapparel.com"],
  "domain_action_type": "add"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

then set "messenger_extensions" to true on the URL and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the page dashboard to do so:

- open the page you manage
- Click https://web.facebook.com/settings?tab=advanced_messaging
- Whitelisted domains
- then add the domain

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vba6L.png)